# Mapping phone numbers to names

Tags: c++, file-system, search, hash-map

Problem description:

> You are given **a phone book that consists of your friend's names and
>   their phone number**. After that you will be given your friend's name
>   as query. For each query, print the phone number of your friend.
>
> The first line will have an integer N denoting the number of entries
>   in the phone book. Each entry consists of two lines: a name and the
>   corresponding phone number.
>
> After these, there will be some queries. Each query will contain name
>   of a friend. Read the queries **until end-of-file.**
>
> For each case, print "Not found" without quotes, if the friend has no
>   entry in the phone book. Otherwise, print the friend's name and phone
>   number. See sample output for the exact format.

**Sample input:**

```
3
sam
99912222
tom
11122222
harry
12299933
sam
edward
harry
```

**Sample output:**

```
sam=99912222
Not found
harry=12299933
```

**My solution:**

```
int main() 
   {    
    map<string, string> PhoneList;

    int n;

    string name,ph,str;

    while(n--)

        {

         cin>>name>>ph;

         PhoneList[name] = ph;

        }

    while( getline (cin,t) )

      { 
          cin>>str;

          auto it = PhoneList.find(str);

               if(it==PhoneList.end())

                  cout<<"Not Found\n";

               else

                  cout<<it->second;
      }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I'm afraid this question does not match what this site is about. Code Review is about improving existing, working code. Code Review is not the site to ask for help in fixing or changing *what* your code does. Once the code does what you want, we would love to help you do the same thing in a cleaner way! Please see our [help center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more information.

Comment: Does it work as intended? Are you interested in feedback on any & all aspects of the code? Please [edit] to clarify your post.

Comment: The code as it stands doesn't compile - and even if it would it wouldn't match the given specification. So it's definitely off-topic I'd say

Comment: @Edward it does not work properly .. like i had problems with reading strings until eof ... i got it now... thank you !!

Comment: @Mat'sMug yeah i jus had doubts regarding the reading until eof ... thank you !

Comment: @Edward i ll stick to the rules ! thank you  !!

Comment: @ChrisWue i jus got what code review is all about ! thank you !

Comment: @sindhuja No worries. If you need help to make it work then Stack Overflow would probably be a good place to ask (just check out their Help Center in regards of how to best ask questions). Once you got it working we're happy to review what you have.

Comment: @ChrisWue                                                                                                                     yeah ! thanks !  ..Do i need to edit my post since its off topic ? But then i had problems with the code which i got it cleared..So do i need to edit ? Sorry to hav put up the post here ..

Comment: Since there is now an answer you should post a follow up question with your improved code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your program, some of them rendering it non-functional. As it is a very simple one, it does not take much time to fix it, but as already specified by Edward, you should submit only working code that requires reviewing.

1) **Code aspect**

You should try to keep you code as organized and homogeneous as possible. Usually, it is not required for homework, but it is good in a programmer's life:

```
int main() 
   {    
    map<string, string> PhoneList;

    int n;
```

should be properly formatted like

```
int main() 
{    
   map<string, string> PhoneList;

   int n;
```

Try to leave blanks between operators and operands, as this will increase readability:

```
string name,ph,str;
```

should be replaced with

```
string name, ph, str;
```

2) **Variable declaration closer to usage**

C++ allows you to declare your variables anywhere before they are actually used and it is a good idea to be as close as possible. The first part of your program may look like this:

```
int n;
cout << "Provide number of entries: ";
cin >> n;

map<string, string> PhoneList;
while (n --)
{
    string name, phone;

    // this is added just to see something relevant on the screen - it might be removed
    cout << "Name " << (n + 1) << ":\n";
    cin >> name;

    cout << "Phone " << (n + 1) << ":\n";
    cin >> phone;

    PhoneList[name] = phone;
}
```

3) **getLine** requires a `cin.ignore()` before, as it will catch a newline for a previously entered phone (at least when testing manually)

Finally, a version of your program with all improvements made:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{    
    int n;
    cout << "Provide number of entries: ";
    cin >> n;

    map<string, string> PhoneList;
    while (n --)
    {
        string name, phone;

        cout << "Name " << (n + 1) << ":\n";
        cin >> name;

        cout << "Phone " << (n + 1) << ":\n";
        cin >> phone;

        PhoneList[name] = phone;
    }

    string str;
    cin.ignore();
    while(getline(cin, str))
    { 
        auto it = PhoneList.find(str);
        if (it == PhoneList.end())
            cout << "Not Found\n";
        else
            cout << it->second << "\n";
    }
}
```

This is tested in [cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh/)

Comment: ...i ll make sure of the format next time !

Comment: is this the best way of doing this ? I mean ...can we optimise it further?